# How to select href value in regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to get the all href values, but could not get coorect result please help us.

I have tried this pattern

(?[\w-]+)\s*=\s*((?:"(?[^">]+)))

this is the link
https://rubular.com/r/QBhBViYSWCyz4j

Sample:

```
<a href="#" lclick="Test_Navi('page:6f66f6dd')">
<A HREF = "page:9477be:The Page "Test Detail"">

**Output**:

Match 1:
Name    href
Value   #

Match 2:
Name:   lclick
Value:  Test_Navi('page:6f66f6dd')

Match 3:
Name:   HREF
Value:  page:9477be:Der Dialog

**Expected Output**:
Match 1:
Name    href
Value   #

Match 2:
Name    lclick
Value   Test_Navi('page:6f66f6dd')

Match 3:
Name    HREF
Value   page:9477be:Der Dialog "Test Detail"
```

Comment: What is the expected output? what's wrong with that regex you're using? You only want to match href?

Comment: Hm... `(?<Name>href)\s*=\s*((["']?(?<Value>[^"'>]+)))` ?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse structured formats. A fluffy kitten meets its slow, tortured death each time you do.

Comment: @ALFA, I have updated my question.

Comment: @mishik, Thanks, But your pattern is not giving my expected result.

Comment: Why your `<a>` tag contain spaces and invalid link ?

Comment: @SUПΣYΛ, for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you shouldn't use regex to parse/process html but for simple text extraction you can use this regex to get your desired matches from group1,

```
\w+\s*=\s*"([^=]*)"
```

**Explanation:**

- `\w+` - Matches one or more word `\w` (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) character
- `\s*=\s*` - Matches `=` surrounded by optional whitespace character(s)
- `"([^=]*)"` - This is the key part of the regex which differentiates it from other answers and makes it work like expected. The values you wanted to capture also contained doublequotes within them hence `[^"]+` couldn't be used and using `".*"` would capture more than desired. The key here is that all your key-value pairs are separated by `=` hence the value can't contain this character, due to which I used `[^=]*` character to capture the value and in greedy way so any of the doublequotes present inside also gets captured expect the last ones which is where `"([^=]*)"` is needed and makes the job done as you wanted.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gloiRv/1)**

And your extended version of regex to be this,

```
(?<Name>[\w-]+)\s*=\s*((?:"(?<Value>[^=]+)"))
```

**[Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/jbekPCsyxc98m4)**

Comment: Thanks, It's working, Could you explain the expression to me.

Comment: @user6479492: Sure, let me add explanation to my answer.

Comment: <A HREF ="http://mycompany.com/enc=EncRypTedValue="> this is not match, pls help us.

Comment: Ok, now as you have `=` in the value part too, you can use this regex `\w+\s*=\s*"(\S*|[^=]*)"` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gloiRv/2) And your Rubular demo regex becomes, `(?<Name>[\w-]+)\s*=\s*((?:"(?<Value>\S*|[^=]+)"))` [Rubular Demo](https://rubular.com/r/Lc2P9ZUe2c2KDQ)

Comment: Thanks, Could you explain the expression '\S*' means.

Comment: `\S*` means zero or more non-whitespace characters. Hence in your case, when there is a `=` in the value, I used `\S*` to capture them.

Answer (score 1):

if you realy need the name / value stuff then
instead of all the words use `href`
[\w-]+ => href

```
(?<name>href)\s*=\s*((?:"(?<Value>[^">]+)))
```